# Can LLVM jitter emit the native code in continus memory addresses?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, jit

I have question relating to LLVM Jitter:
Can i obligue the LLVM Jitter to emit the native code in continuous memory addresses ? and to be PIC ?
what i want to do is to move save the JIT code in a file and load it for execution later ..

what i mean by "load" is to simply read the bits from file into buffer i don't want to generate elf or something like this.

Here's an example:
suppose i have C source file which contain:

```
Global variables
----------------
Function Foo()
----------------
Function Too()
```

when i request the JIT code i want the JIT to be in continus memory addresses:

```
0x100: Global Vars (take 16 Byte)
0x110: Foo() Code (take 32 Byte)
0x130: Too() Code (take 32 Byte)
0x150: end.
```

Comment: Why do you want to use JIT to do this? It sounds like a job for regular compiler. Why are you avoiding ELfs? Creating shared library would save you a lot of work. NSAM can output [Flat-Form Binary](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoc6.html) but I doubt executing them would be that easy.

Comment: i don't see full support of elf in LLVM for X86, am i wrong ?
the 2nd problem that if i choose to generate elf i need loader in order to execute the code - and this what i am trying to avoid.
the problem is that i want to execute the jit in another Process so i need to move the JIT code to the execution process.

Comment: IIRC, x86 ELF should be one of the best-supported code generators, along with PowerPC. llvm.org seems to have a downtime right now, so I can't check. (Edit: Found 2.9 Release notes in the Google cache, search for "known problems with the x86 backend" and observe how small it is: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TRAHCRHR-D8J:llvm.org/releases/2.9/docs/ReleaseNotes.html+llvm+release+notes+2.9&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&source=www.google.de)

Comment: yes i see that, the problem is that i still use LLVM2.8 rightnow and it seems there's no support for ELF. Morever as i said assume that i have an ELF file i still need loader, so i am still avoiding this way and turn to something like "JIT"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store JIT'ed code in some region of memory you can write special version of JITMemoryManager (`include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/JITMemoryManager.h` `lib/ExecutionEngine/JIT/JITMemoryManager.cpp`). There is example of custom JIM MM here: `unittests/ExecutionEngine/JIT/JITTest.cpp`, it is an `RecordingJITMemoryManager` which logs main JIT MM calls.

As I can see (as LLVM 2.9), ARM JIT have `isPIC` set to False and X86 JIT is capable of generating PIC code.

The biggest problem, seems, is loading of precompiled code.